# Windows server 2008 uses outdated cipher suites？

Tags: iis-7.5, tls1.2

the default cipher suite of windows 2008: AES_**CBC is out of date. I tried to update the patch in exchange for a new cipher suite: AES***GCM. Failed, I don’t know if Microsoft provides AES**_GCM new cipher suite patches on windows 2008.

Comment: Currently, Microsoft's support for Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2 has been terminated. For details, you can refer to this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4456235/end-of-support-for-windows-server-2008-and-windows-server-2008-r2

Comment: 1) Move away from Windows Server 2008 as it is end of life. 2) Microsoft has some cipher suites update for that legacy system https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows but again you get no technical support now.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 R2 don't support ECDHE+RSA+AESGCM cipher it just support ECDHE+ECDSA+AESGCM OR DHE+RSA+AESGCM so you can't use ECDHE with gcm cipher if you use RSA certificate

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).